# Google Drive Java Api : Is it possible to Extract zip file that is available in google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Is there a way to unzip a zip file that is available in google drive using google drive java api.

i Am able to retrieve all the files from a particular users drive , now what i need to do is, if a file is a zip file, i need to extract it and get the files available inside it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to download the file and extract it locally.

Comment: i need to read the content of file by program and make some operations in my application basing on the content

Comment: that's what he said, yes